# TortoiseSVN - Global ignore pattern not working for thumbs.db

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, thumbnails, svnignore

How do I manage to make TortoiseSVN (64 Bit on Windows 8) ignore all Thumbs.db files? I know that Settings->Global Ignore Pattern exists. I entered

```
*.db Thumbs.db thumbs.db
```

among the other entries that where there by default. But TortoiseSVN still does not ignore the Thumbs.db files. They pop up as new files that ToirtoiseSVN wants to add and commit to the repo.

Do I have to change some other settings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, if you want to ignore those, use

```
[Tt]humbs.[dD][bB]
```

as the ignore pattern.

Second: when you use the global ignore pattern in the TSVN settings dialog, that change will take up to five minutes to take effect (because the value is cached).

Although, in your case ignoring won't work: Subversion never ignores files that are already under version control! (you mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743013/tortoisesvn-global-ignore-pattern-not-working-for-thumbs-db#comment18888418_13744489) that the overlay icon changes to a red exclamation mark, which means that file is under version control). You have to first delete the file from SVN, commit and then ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. Seems the site is down for maintanance. But there are other sites explaining how to disable Thumbs.db in Windows, for example: http://www.pawprint.net/news/article/84/Prevent-Windows-7-Thumbs-db-Files/

Answer (score 0):

You can use global (per user on *this host*, any Subversion-client) ignore settings, applicable to any OS

`%APPDATA%/Subversion/config`, `[miscellany]` section, `global-ignores` parameter. Addition of Thumbs.db seems to be OK

Comment: Thanks. I already found this file. adding Thumbs.db and *.db did not change anything (And yes: I uncommented the line in the config file that is a comment by default). Thumbs.db is still not ignored by TortoiseSVN.

Comment: @FooBar - reaction 1: "It's just **IMPOSSIBLE!!!**". Reaction 2: "Any chances you already **have Thumbs.db** versioned in this repo? Pls, show `svn st` for you WC"

Comment: No. I have a brand-new folder with png files without Thumbs.db. I add this folder to SVN. And my SVN is configured to ignore Thumbs.db. Then I open the folder with the pngs and Windows creates the Thumbs.db. The icon on the folder that TortoiseSVN display changes to a red exclamation mark and the commit dialog wants to add Thumbs.db. Let's ask th other way round: Is there a way to prevent Windows from creating this file at all?

Comment: @FooBar - preventing from creating, AFAIK, answer is "No". But you have at least two more possible way to skip these files: 1. Add to ignore-on-commit TSVN changelist (from commit window) 2. Use [svn:ignore](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) property of parent (for Thumbs.db) folder